# PHP no MacOsx Yosemite

Tags: php, osx

Olá, quando executo php --version:

```
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Porém tenho outra versão do php na pasta /usr/local/php5 que gostaria de torna-la padrão ao usar o comando php no terminal, como deveria fazer? Se possível excluir a versão 5.5. Eu uso o fish como shel. Já tentei inserir:

```
if status --is-login
    set PATH $PATH /usr/local/php5
end
```

Porém quando eu uso o terminal via PHPStorm essa configuração já não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem pessoal, resolvi o meu problema setando:

```
set PATH $PATH /usr/local/php5
```

no arquivo de configuração do fish em vez de

```
if status --is-login
  set PATH $PATH /usr/local/php5
end
```